# How to determine why system suspends but fails to resume

Tags: suspend, troubleshooting, chrome-book

How would I go about determining why my Chromebook (Acer CB515-1HT using the SeaBIOS for boot provided by [MrChromeBox](https://mrchromebox.tech).) running Linux Mint suspends successfully but does not resume? When it resumes, it goes to a firmware screen. I can then shut down and power up and all works fine. [NOTE: Since this is happening under Linux Mint, I posted in that forum. also.]

This does not happen under other Ubuntu-based distros; e.g., Pop!_OS 21.10, Ubuntu-Budgie 21.10, Lubuntu 21.10, Ubuntu 21.10 using kernel versions 5.15.15-75051515, 5.13.0-19, 5.13.0-19, and 5.13.0-19, respectively. The main Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon distro is using kernel 5.4.0. So, I tried the Linux Mint Edge edition (kernel 5.13.0-25) and also the MATE and XFCE editions (kernel 5.4.0).  But those LM editions didn't work, either.

Searching the forum I've found several other posts that seem related but haven't seen anything that pertains to actually resolving this issue.

Since the other distros do not exhibit this behavior, it seems I should be able to compare settings, configs, drivers, or something between those and Linux Mint to determine what might be the difference. I have extensive experience working in Windows systems but am relatively new to Linux so would appreciate some guidance on where to start.

**UPDATE**
Output of `sudo inxi -verbosity 8 -- filter`

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic 
  root=UUID=7f54ec77-2248-4c41-90d2-2a01cbc34466 ro quiet splash 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 wm: muffin 5.2.0 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 
  Distro: Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Google product: Sand v: rev3 serial: <filter> 
  Chassis: type: 9 serial: N/A 
  Mobo: Google model: Sand v: rev3 serial: <filter> BIOS: coreboot v: N/A 
  date: 11/29/2018 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 32.2 Wh condition: 40.3/50.5 Wh (80%) volts: 7.8/7.6 
  model: SMP-SDI AC16B7K type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
  cycles: 73 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 3.72 GiB used: 808.0 MiB (21.2%) 
  Array-1: capacity: N/A slots: 0 EC: N/A max module size: N/A 
  Device-1: Channel-0-DIMM-0 size: 1 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: Other 
  detail: synchronous bus width: 16 bits total: 16 bits manufacturer: N/A 
  part-no: MT53B256M32D1NP serial: <filter> 
  Device-2: Channel-1-DIMM-0 size: 1 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: Other 
  detail: synchronous bus width: 16 bits total: 16 bits manufacturer: N/A 
  part-no: MT53B256M32D1NP serial: <filter> 
  Device-3: Channel-2-DIMM-0 size: 1 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: Other 
  detail: synchronous bus width: 16 bits total: 16 bits manufacturer: N/A 
  part-no: MT53B256M32D1NP serial: <filter> 
  Device-4: Channel-3-DIMM-0 size: 1 GiB speed: 2400 MT/s type: Other 
  detail: synchronous bus width: 16 bits total: 16 bits manufacturer: N/A 
  part-no: MT53B256M32D1NP serial: <filter> 
PCI Slots:
  Message: No PCI slot data found. 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Pentium N4200 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Goldmont family: 6 model-id: 5C (92) stepping: 9 microcode: 44 
  L2 cache: 1024 KiB bogomips: 8755 
  Speed: 2388 MHz min/max: 800/2500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2388 2: 2388 
  3: 2388 4: 2363 
  Flags: 3dnowprefetch acpi aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_capabilities 
  arch_perfmon art bts cat_l2 clflush clflushopt cmov constant_tsc cpuid 
  cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts ept ept_ad erms est 
  flexpriority fpu fsgsbase fxsr ht ibpb ibrs ida intel_pt lahf_lm lm mca 
  mce md_clear mmx movbe mpx msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat pbe 
  pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36 pts rdrand rdseed 
  rdt_a rdtscp rep_good sdbg sep sha_ni smap smep ss sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 
  ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust tsc_deadline_timer 
  tsc_known_freq tsc_reliable vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xgetbv1 xsave xsavec 
  xsaveopt xsaves xtopology xtpr 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected 
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected 
  Type: mds status: Not affected 
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected 
  Type: spec_store_bypass status: Not affected 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, 
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds status: Not affected 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
```

Since originally posting, I've moved to kernel 5.13.0-28 as that kernel does contain a driver for the cr50 TPM chip.  But now it hangs on suspend as opposed to suspending correctly and then resetting at resume.  So, while the 5.4.0 kernel doesn't recognize the TPM (and fails on resume), the 5.13.0 kernel recognizes it(?) but hangs on suspend.  Yet, the 5.13.0 kernel in the other distros works correctly.  That just doesn't make sense.  I do not understand why this works fine on *buntu w 5.13 kernel but fails on Linux Mint w 5.13 kernel.  But maybe I need to just go to a new distro and give up on Linux Mint.

Doing a `journalctl -rb -1` (immediately after restart following the hang-on-suspend), it shows that it seems to reach sleep but then doesn't progress beyond the "Filesystms sync".

```
kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.075 seconds
systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Succeeded.
kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
systemd-sleep[1589]: Suspending system...
systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
```

Comparing this with the output of an install of Lubuntu (21.10 w 51.3 kernel), which successfully suspends/resumes, the Lubuntu continues past that point to "Freezing user space processes" and beyond.  (The journal continues with the successful resume but did not include that.)

```
kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
kernel: IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU3
kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
kernel: IRQ 121: no longer affine to CPU2
kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
kernel: IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU1
kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
kernel: OOM killer disabled.
kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.037 seconds
systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
systemd-sleep[2377]: Suspending system...
systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the reply to this [r/GalliumOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/sqmx6f/how_to_determine_why_resume_after_suspend_fails/), article it is because Linux Mint main (kernel 5.4) does not carry a CR50 TPM driver.  I also found this [LWN.net](https://lwn.net/Articles/797949/) article which seemed pertinent.  It is carried in the 5.13 kernel (Linux Mint Edge edition) but then it hangs on suspend with a black screen.